# Trying to use jQuery.data() API to cache a function in a jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, dom-events

Please suggest solutions to below mentioned scenario

**Background (jQuery Plugin):**

```
$.fn.myplugin = function (action) {
    if (actions[action]) {
        return actions[action].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof action === 'object' || !action) {
        return actions.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
        $.error('Action ' + action + ' does not exist on myplugin');
        return this;
    }
};
```

and variable **actions** looking like:

```
var actions = {
    init: function (options) {
        if (this.length) {
            var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.myplugin.defaults);
            return this.each(function () {
                if (options) {
                    settings = $.extend(settings, options);
                }

                $(this).data('myplugin', new MyPlugin($(this), settings));
            });
        } else {
            throw new Error('unable to init undefined');
        }
    },
    update: function () {
        ...
    },
    destroy: function () {
        ...
    }
};
```

and **MyPlugin** looking like

```
function MyPlugin($el, settings) {
    var $content = $('.content', $el);

    var a = function setup() { ... };

    var b = function hold() { ... }

    $content.on({
        'click': function(e) { ... },
        'hover': function(e) { ... }
    });
}
```

I get that I can dump $.cache to console and see what gets associated in .data().

**Problem/Suggestions wanted:**

If I call the update function like `$('myEle').myplugin('update')` then I need the `update function` to change state of the instance of MyPlugin created and cached using `.data()` API. What are the possible ways to do that?

My current result of `$('myEle').data('myplugin')` shows `MyPlugin{}` with nothing between the curly braces.

Comment: From your snippet, you haven't actually assigned any instance members to `MyPlugin`.  The var's `a`, `b` and `$content` are caught in a closure, but aren't members of `MyPlugin` as such.  i.e. you are missing a `this.foo = bar` inside the `MyPlugin` constructor

Comment: @searlea please put this up as the answer. Exactly what I was doing wrong. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem doesn't have anything to do with jQuery or the `data()` API, it's due to a misunderstanding about functions, objects and constructors in JavaScript.

This is easy to test inside the JavaScript console in a browser:

```
> function MyPlugin() { var a = 1; var b = 2; }
undefined
> new MyPlugin()
MyPlugin {}

> function MyPlugin() { this.a = 1; this.b = 2; }
undefined
> new MyPlugin()
MyPlugin {a: 1, b: 2}
```